# Persist url parameters across requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-parameters

I am using Spring MVC. There is a requirement that some user selections remain globally and always in the url parameter. I might also be able to remove it with code at will.

Is there something like Persistent Page Data(like in Tapestry http://tapestry.apache.org/persistent-page-data.html) for Spring MVC.

A link to a similar quesion thats unanswered: http://osdir.com/ml/java.appfuse.user/2005-08/msg00507.html
Thanks

*Update*

Eventually I used a simple technique, where:
1. I would capture the current page url with query paramters.
2. Add or replace the new parameters into this url.

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></c:set>
<c:set var="servletPath" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}"></c:set>
<c:set var="currentPath" value="${contextPath}${servletPath}"></c:set>

<a href="${fn:replaceUrlParameter(currentPath,'age','1') }">ageone</a>
```

where replaceUrlParameter() uses regex to replace or add the query parameter.

Comment: You should probably throw it into the users session instead.

Comment: I wanted the parameters in the url so that search engines could index such pages too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep this parameters in session and write the Servlet Filter that would add them to any request or would modify request URL so they are visible in URL.

Comment: Looks like a neat solution. I will try and implement this.